# Tomcat web application and browser url

Tags: web-applications, indexing, tomcat7

I have a webapp extensions.war deployed in tomcat 7. The war has index.html on top level. When user say `http://server:port/extensions/`   it brings up index.html.

I want to create two more html pages namely indexOne.html and indexTwo.html under extensions.war.

How can user use url such as `http://http://server:port/extensions/appOne`  and `http://http://server:port/extensions/appTwo` such that these point to extensions.war/indexOne.html and extensions.war/indexTwo.html respectively.

Comment: You can accepts and promote my answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it by the web.xml configuration. The welcome-file-list support only the top level files.
Please note, that URls `extensions/appOne` and `extensions/appTwo` are not top level files.

You can create your own filter that serve your own index html files:

```
if (isRequestTo(request,"appOne")) {
response.sendRedirect("/indexOne.html");
} 
if (isRequestTo(request,"appTwo")) {
response.sendRedirect("/indexTwo.html");
} 


public static boolean isRequestTo(HttpServletRequest request, String urlPart) {
    return request.getRequestURI().startsWith(urlPart);
}
```